# Trouble stacking items horizontally and vertically in same flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap flexbox container and I'm trying to make the image on the left remain horizontal, but have the title, description, and powered by sections, all stack vertically to the right of it. However, whenever I try to change the alignment the only options I've been able to find are to stack all content boxes either horizontally or vertically. I'd like to avoid floats, but how is it possible to align an image horizontally and the three different text sections vertically?

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end flex-row my-flex-container ">
            <div class="mr-auto p-2 my-flex-item"><img src="./images/webimage.png" alt="Mountain View"></div>                
            <div class="p-2 my-flex-item hello">Quoriron</div>
            <div class="p-2 my-flex-item hello">Quoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an APIQuoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an APIQuoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an API</div>            
            <div class="p-2 my-flex-item hello">Powered by: React, Rails</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use flex *column wrap* flow, give the container a height, set the height to the image flex item to 100%, or add a wrapper for the text items.

With the *column* direction, you still might end up with yet another wrap on the text, so for a dynamic, response solution, I recommend to go with the extra wrapper.

*Note, you need to adjust the Bootstrap classes accordingly, which I didn't*

*Note 2, and, as you said yourself, `float` can of course do this, if the markup can't be changed.*

Stack snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end flex-row my-flex-container ">
            <div class="mr-auto p-2 my-flex-item"><img src="./images/webimage.png" alt="Mountain View"></div>                
            <div class="p-2 my-flex-item hello">
              <div>Quoriron</div>
              <div>Quoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an APIQuoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an APIQuoriron is a Quora clone, made with React/Redux and using Ruby-on-Rails as an API</div>            
              <div>Powered by: React, Rails</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so basically when i need to achieve this effect, it's best to have two flex items that align horizontally, and then nest divs that vertically align within one of those flex items? thank you!

Comment: @Dog Correct, since Flexbox doesn't have a good, dynamic way to accomplish this...e.g. like CSS Grid has